# Pointers and Char arrays issue

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

Ok so this code does compile, and it does run, but it does NOT give me the correct output for EITHER the original or reverse array, just gibberish. I spent the last 4 hours trying to see where I went wrong (it wasn't working at all before and now that I got it to at least output what SHOULD be a C-string, i get gibberish). Someone please help me see where I went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


char* getInput();
char* getReverse(char[], int);
void displayResults(char *, char *);

const int MAX_SIZE = 21;

int main()
{
    //program to create a c-string and then output the reverse order
    char *original;
    char *reverse;
    original = getInput();
    int originalSize = strlen(original);
    reverse = getReverse(original, originalSize);
    displayResults(original, reverse);
    return 0;
}

/***************************************************
Definition of function- getInput:                  *
prompts the user to enter in a line of text to a   *
max amount of characters. Returns a pointer to the *
C-string array.                                    *
****************************************************/
char* getInput()
{
    char *originalptr;
    char original[MAX_SIZE];
    cout << "Enter a word or line of text up to a max of 20 characters\nand will     have it output in reverse!" << endl;
    cin.getline(original, MAX_SIZE);
    originalptr = original;
    return originalptr;
}

char* getReverse(char *reverseThis, int size)
{

    char* reverseOutput;
    char reverse[MAX_SIZE];
    int counter = 0;
    while(*reverseThis != '\0')
    {
        reverse[counter] = *(reverseThis + (size - counter));
        reverseThis++;
        counter++;
    }
    reverseOutput = reverse;
    return reverseOutput;

}

void displayResults(char *original, char *reverse)
{   
    cout << "\nYou originally entered: " << original << endl;
    cout << "In reverse order: " << reverse << endl;
}
```

Comment: you're returning `&original` from `getInput` which is undefined behavior btw. Likewise for `getReverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'getReverse' you are allocating the variable 'reverse' on the STACK meaning the data will be GONE WHEN THE FUNCTION RETURNS, no matter how many pointers reference that data.

I would declare 'reverse' in main with 'char reverse[MAX_SIZE];', then have the function take a parameter 'char reverse[]', which the function would then modify.

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it was something silly like that! Just after hours of trying to debug you can forget things and overlook them easily, especially when still learning!

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to a local array. The array `original` is destroyed after the function `getInput` exits. So `original` in main is pointing at something which no longer exists, garbage in other words. `getReverse` has exactly the same problem.

One way to solve this is to declare the arrays in main, and pass pointers to those arrays to the `getInput` and `getReverse` functions, for instance.

```
int main()
{
    //program to create a c-string and then output the reverse order
    char original[MAX_SIZE];
    char reverse[MAX_SIZE];
    getInput(original);
    int originalSize = strlen(original);
    getReverse(original, originalSize, reverse);
    displayResults(original, reverse);
    return 0;
}

void getInput(char* original)
{
    cout << "Enter a word or line of text up to a max of 20 characters\nand will     have it output in reverse!" << endl;
    cin.getline(original, MAX_SIZE);
}

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wasting too much char* s and data. Why not try this :
(I have not tested the code, but it must work ,probably with minor fixes,if any.)

```
    #define MAXSIZE 20
    void getinput(char *in)
{    
   cin.getline(in,MAXSIZE);
return;

}
    void reverse(char *in);     
    {
        int len=strlen(in);
char *store=in;        
while(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
{
char temp;
temp=*in;
*in=*(store+len);
in++;len--;
}
return;
    }
    int main()
    {
char data[MAXSIZE];
    getinput(data);
cout<<"Original :"<<data;
reverse(data);
cout<<"reverse"<<data;
    }
```